# Why is there a full-screen white flash when I load this website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am working on a site: http://deel.io

When the page loads, there is a half-second or so white flash that appears on the screen.

The white flash goes away if I comment out the line of code that puts the markers on the map:

```
markersArray[i].setMap(map);
```

Yet this flash has only just started appearing, so it must be some other code that is causing the above code now to cause the flash.

I realize this is impossibly difficult to help with *unless you've seen it before.* That's what I'm hoping for--that someone had this exact thing happen to them and knows right away what I am probably doing wrong.

My code is basically all JS/jQuery.

Please see edit below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced the problem using Chrome once, every other time after that I couldn't see the white flash. Even with different browsers.

Your probably going to have backtrack all your changes until the problem goes away to see what you introduced that's causing the problem. Hopefully you've been using source control.

I hope you get more replies - although this is a very specific issue that I could only repro once.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. The flash only shows in Chrome and only once per tab. Refreshes in the same tab don't show the white flash!

Comment: a bit more research and appparently its common on android phones http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3646 - this thread has a possible cause and that's where I'd start - checking the DOM changes when the flash occurs. HTH